# Lenovo p52 with Ubuntu 18.04 issues

Tags: 18.04, graphics, multiple-monitors, lenovo, hdmi

I just received my new Lenovo p52 and I quickly installed the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on it but I have some issues. I will list them below:

- on screen lock I can't get it to unlock. Hard reset with the button is needed.
- I want to use the hybrid graphics and HDMI but Ubuntu says no.It is not booting up at all when I change the BIOS option.
- I tried to with the dedicated graphics card to put the HDMI, all works fine until the moment I want to make the laptop screen primary and the monitor secondary but one on top of the other. When I hit apply to this option I get logged out from Ubuntu ....

I was thinking to update the kernel to the latest Gnome but I not 100% sure if I should do this (know-how).

Any kind of suggestions are kindly appreciated.

Comment: Trying to do the same on a P52s with openSUSE Tumbleweed, Gnome/Wayland and having a heck of a time, but no issues with HDMI. Being it's been a few months, have you had any luck? I'll post my successes when I have some :P

Comment: After a simple update/upgrade in ubuntu things got better but still having issues. My solution was to return the laptop. After some time i discovered that the P52 with video P1000 has issues on the video cooling system and the only thing is to lower the voltage on the processor via a python script. more info on the lenovo forum / linux something with heat and throttling